# How to connect a remote jms client to an embedded activemq broker in tomcat?

Tags: xml, activemq-classic

I have an embedded broker in tomcat that my webapp clients are connecting to fine using vm://localhost.  I would like some remote clients in another jvm be able to connect to the embedded broker.  How do I set up the embedded broker to listen on a port#?  This works for embedded clients:

server.xml fragment:

```
<Resource auth="Container" 
name="jms/ConnectionFactory" 
type="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" 
description="JMS Connection Factory" 
factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory" 
brokerURL="vm://localhost" 
brokerName="MyActiveMQBroker" 
useEmbeddedBroker="true"/>
```

This isn't working for remote clients, but my embedded clients still connect using vm://localhost:

```
<Resource auth="Container" 
name="jms/ConnectionFactory" 
type="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" 
description="JMS Connection Factory" 
factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory" 
brokerURL="vm:(broker:(tcp://localhost:61616))" 
brokerName="MyActiveMQBroker" 
useEmbeddedBroker="true"/>
```

My remote clients give this error:

Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

I also have been trying this:

```
brokerURL="vm://localbroker?brokerConfig=xbean:file:C:/temp/activemq.xml"
```

and in the activemq.xml, setting this:

```
<transportConnectors>
<transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616"/>
</transportConnectors>

<networkConnectors>
<networkConnector uri="static:(tcp://0.0.0.0:61616)"/>
</networkConnectors>
```

I don't believe the xml file is getting read, because my symptoms never change when editing it.  On tomcat startup, when the first client webapp deploys, the broker starts and reports that:

Connector vm://localhost Started

I never see another connector started, like tcp://0.0.0.0:61616.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

`vm://localhost` will not open tcp port for remote broker to connect. vm protocol can be used within JVM.

Configuration on your local tomcat (e.g. consider local server with hostname as "tomcathostone")

```
<Resource auth="Container" 
name="jms/ConnectionFactory" 
type="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" 
description="JMS Connection Factory" 
factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory" 
brokerURL="broker:(tcp://0.0.0.0:61616)" 
brokerName="MyActiveMQBroker" 
useEmbeddedBroker="true"/>
```

Configuration on your remote tomcat (e.g. consider remote server with hostname as "tomcathosttwo")

```
<Resource auth="Container" 
name="jms/ConnectionFactory" 
type="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" 
description="JMS Connection Factory" 
factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory" 
brokerURL="broker:(tcp://tomcathosttwo:61616,network:static:tcp://tomcathostone:61616)" 
brokerName="MyActiveMQBroker" 
useEmbeddedBroker="true"/>
```

Comment: I have used the configuration with brokerURL="broker:(tcp://0.0.0.0:61616)" in Tomcat 7 server.xml but I have bumped in the error:   nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [broker]. Do you know what is the reason for this issue?

Comment: @Satish Hi Please could you give some clue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706788/integration-of-restful-wvb-service-with-activemq/19751507?noredirect=1#19751507

Comment: I have a similar question can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62313720/cannot-access-embedded-activemq-within-kubernetes-cluster/62313961#62313961