# cannot access embedded ActiveMq within kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, activemq-classic, kubernetes-pod

We are starting an embedded activeMq server in our java application. This will run in a kubernetes pod.

```
broker = BrokerFactory.createBroker("broker:(tcp://localhost:41415)?persistent=false");
broker.setBrokerId("ActiveMqBroker" + 1);
broker.setUseJmx(false);
broker.start();
```

Now we have one application which accesses it inside the same pod. This works fine.

However when another application accesses this activemq server from another pod using service name like tcp://service.hostname:41415 then it does not work.

I also tried adding a connector to service.hostname but it throws `java.net.BindException: Address not available (Bind failed)`.

```
broker.addConnector("tcp://service.hostname:41415");
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Edit:

My pod deployment+service yaml looks like

```html
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
  labels:
    app: activemq
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: activemq
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: activemq
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: activemq
        image: <myimage>
        ports:
        - containerPort: 41415
```

```html
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service.hostname
spec:
  selector:
    app: activemq
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 41415
      targetPort: 41415
```

Comment: How to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to expose the ports for that pod, so that other services can access it.

Please refer: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/

ex.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello
      tier: backend
      track: stable
  replicas: 7
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello
        tier: backend
        track: stable
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello
          image: "gcr.io/google-samples/hello-go-gke:1.0"
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
```

Comment: hi, i will update my question but I am already exposing the port for the pod in both deployment and service yaml. it still does not work.